# Using GlassFish for a socket server application

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a java server application which uses sockets to communicate with clients. Application needs to have load balancing, session sharing among instances and database connection pooling. Currently this is an standalone application without load balancing.

Is it possible to use an application server like GlassFish to host this server application? If it is, how should I do it?

I need to remind that this is NOT a web application.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

It is possible. Web apps can create their own threads or thread pools.  Unless prevented from doing so by a security policy, they can open sockets and listen.

You won't benefit from glassfish session management, as that is part of the HTTP stack. You'll have to have a servlet, or servlet-context-listener whose only job is to initialize your application on startup.  That is a bit weird, when there is no web content, but I guess it is ok.  Web apps are often deployed on machines that might only have web ports open to them in the firewall (80, 443, etc).   You could add a HTTP page to the app for administration/monitoring, and make it a web app, at least partially.

Comment: Application servers have many features which java server applications (say a messenger server, or an SMSC) can use. I haven't seen any tutorial or book that use application servers for things other than web development, which sounds weird to me. :/